# What is the probability of two things happening at the same time?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I am using the normal distribution for two events so there is a 34% chance of each event having one standard deviation above the mean.

What is the probability of both events having one standard deviation above the mean at the same time?

Is it just 0.34*0.34  ?

Comment: Your answer is correct if both the events are independent.

Comment: What if they are dependent?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality, see this article on the section two correlated variables, it becomes slightly ugly with correlation coefficient coming into bounds.